# reading and changing .txt file via Hash Table

Tags: perl

I'm trying hard to understand how to set up a Hash table - which is what I imagine I need, if I understand the 'Introduction to Perl' book, and various suggestions on the web etc. I have to read a .text/csv file which looks like this - semicolons and all:

```
PRENOM;NOM;SEXE;AGE;PAYS;TITRE;GENRE
Cédrick;Matisse;m;25-45;Belgique;La peinture de l'amour;romance
Anne-Pascale;Ork;f;15-25;Belgique;La dernière halte des elfes;fantastique
Anne-Pascale;Ork;f;15-25;Belgique;La tentation du gobelin;fantastique
```

....It's just and extract.

I imagine that 1) I should place all this into a hash-table so as to read the individual information being asked for: sex, age, type of book. However I can't seem to understand how to load this into a hash table - even after reading various posts and 'the' Perl book. My code I've been working with looks like this :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $fichier = $ARGV[0]; # fichier source

open( DONNEES, '<', $fichier )
or die("Impossible d'ouvrir le fichier $fichier\n");

my %sexe = ( 'f' => 0, 'm' => 0);

my %age = ( '0-15' => 0, '15-25' => 0, '25-45' => 0, '45-65' => 0, '65-' => 0 );

my %genre = ( 'art' => 0, 'divers' => 0, 'education' => 0,
         'essai' => 0, 'fantastique' => 0, 'informatique' => 0,
         'pratique' => 0, 'roman' => 0, 'romance' =>0,
         'sci-fi' => 0);

my $sexe = 0;
my $sexem = 0;

print "$fichier\n";

while ( my $ligne = <DONNEES> ) {

chomp($ligne);

# decoupage de chaque ligne du fichier en 6 colonnes
my ($prenom, $nom, $sexe, $age, $pays, $livre, $genre ) = split( /\t/, $ligne );
```

etc .....

When working with a document with spaces already placed in them it seemed easy to work with arrays, place them in a column and read them. However, here there's a lot more information.
Problems are

1) how can I get my program to ignore the first line of my document (PRENOM;NOM;etc)?

2) How can I then space and place the items needed into the right hash tables? Is the fact that the program reads the whole line with the semicolons one of the problems?

I haven't included any more as this is an assignment for a class, which means I have to figure the rest out myself. After being able to read the individual elements mentioned above, my program will simply have to print out how many 'females' or 'males', how many read 'romances' etc.

Lastly, if the question is not clear OR/AND I'm barking up the wrong tree please don't hesitate to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of modules which can help you in order to get that task done. For example, [Text::CSV::Slurp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV%3a%3aSlurp) converts CSV into an array of hashes.

Comment: Okay, I'm going over to look at that now. Thanks that's a start.

Comment: I've just had a quick look at the Text::CSV::Slurp. Actually it's a later part of the course, after the Easter vacation I think. I must say I'm not sure why the teacher doesn't show us this first, although I guess he has something else in mind.

Comment: I've quickly looked at and tried to include the 'use text::csv::slurp' into my program, along with some code to convert the .csv file. However, I notice the warnings tell my that the program can't locate the text/csv/slurp.pm .. Does this mean I have to download a file and place it in my Perl program?

Comment: yes, it's a CPAN module, you can install it with this command: cpan install Text::CSV::Slurp

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Tie::Array::CSV](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV) is really close to what you need:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

sub get_column {
  my $last = int rand 10;
  return map { rand 100 } (0..$last);
}

tie my @out, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'outfile.csv';

for my $column (0..9) {
  my $row = 0;
  $out[$row++][$column] = $_ for get_column();
}
```

See also a [post by the author](http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2013/03/a-case-for-tiearraycsv.html) explaining the reasoning behind that module.

Comment: Thanks again. But my file could be in text also, does this make a difference? As I mentioned above my warnings keep telling me that it can't locate the TEXT::CSV::SLURP.pm ... what is this, and where can I find it?

Comment: Just bookmarked you site which looks packed with helpful information, a nice find, thanks.

Comment: You may have to install it from the CPAN.